Orientation of boundary $\partial_2$ on torus (and other CW complexes)?
This is a simple and stupid question, but I still can't figure out how the map $\partial_2$ gets oriented. For the torus $T$:

Hatcher and Wikipedia give the boundary as:
$$ \partial_2 U = a + b - c = \partial_2 L $$
I was under the impression that I can orient the boundary chain for a 2--simplex by drawing a clockwise spinor in the center and orienting the edges from it:

Looking at the outer edges of the triangle gives $(a + b - c)$ for $U$, but gives $(c - a - b) = - U $ for $L$, which is different than Hatcher and Wikipedia. Finally, trying to define the simplices in terms of the vertices and naively apply the boundary homomorphism doesn't work for me either, as $v_0 =  v_1 = v_2 = v$. I've combed through Hatcher's book and tried to find help online, but nothing has helped me with this. How do you consistently compute the boundary for simplices of this form?

You need to give the orientation of a simplex based on the orientation of existing edges. In this example, for $U$, the orientation you give is the same as $a$, $b$, and opposite to $c$. Therefore, for L, you need to give the same orientation as $a$, $b$, and opposite to $c$, because in $U$ and $L$, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the same.

This sounds like just a mismatch of orientation conventions. But it would help if you could give a precise reference to the location of this discussion and sketch in Hatcher's book.

@LeeMosher The sketch is on page 102 of Hatcher, and this discussion is on page 106 of Hatcher, example 2.3.

In order to define a $\Delta$-complex, you need to orient each simplex, and that orientation comes from an ordering on the vertices. In this case it's a little confusing because the vertices are all identified, so maybe it's clearer to put a $\Delta$-complex structure on the square with no identifications, and then do the gluing later. Note, though, that the gluing has to be compatible with the orientations.
Start by labeling the bottom left vertex of the square as $v_0$ and the bottom right vertex as $v_1$. Then the bottom edge is oriented from left to right (from the vertex with the smaller index to the vertex with the larger index), so because of the eventual gluing, the top edge has to be oriented the same way, so we label the top vertices as $v_2$ (top left) and $v_3$ (top right). This gives a picture like yours, except the vertices have different labels.

Now we can compute the boundaries of $U$ and $L$: the boundary of a 2-simplex is obtained as the alternating sum of the edges you get by removing the 0th vertex, then the 1st, then the 2nd. Since the vertices of $U$ (in order, and that's important) are $(v_0, v_2, v_3)$, the boundary of $U$ is $(v_2, v_3) - (v_0, v_3) + (v_0, v_2)$. Similarly, since $L$ has vertices $(v_0, v_1, v_3)$, its boundary is $(v_1, v_3) - (v_0, v_3) + (v_0, v_1)$.
(If we go back a stage, this boundary formula is also the reason that the edges are oriented as they are: the boundary of the edge connecting $v_0$ and $v_2$ is $v_2 - v_0$: alternating sum where you first omit the lower vertex, then you have a minus sign where you omit the larger vertex. The convention for orienting an edge is that in its boundary, the "source" has a minus sign and the "target" has a plus sign.)
Now do the gluing and relabel the edges as in your picture.

To expand on the comments, the standard one uses to compute the boundary of a triangle $T$ does not match some pre-determined choice of what you are calling a "spinor".
Instead, the boundary of a triangle $T$ is chosen to match given orientations of the edges of $T$ under the assumption that the three vertices of $T$ can be ordered as $v_0,v_1,v_2$ so that the following holds:

The edge of $T$ denoted $[v_0,v_1]$ with endpoints $v_0,v_1$ is oriented from $v_0$ to $v_1$;
The edge of $T$ denoted $[v_1,v_2]$ with endpoints $v_1,v_2$ is oriented from $v_1$ to $v_2$;
The edge of $T$ denoted $[v_0,v_2]$ with endpoints $v_0,v_2$ is oriented from $v_0$ to $v_2$.

When a vertex labelling of $T$ exists satisfying these properties, it is unique, and the boundary of $T$ is given by the formula
$$\partial T = [v_0,v_1] + [v_1,v_2] - [v_0,v_2]
$$
So now consider the $UL$ diagram from Hatcher that you reproduced in your post. In that diagram, all vertices of the triangles $U$ and $L$ are labelled $v$ because they those vertices all have the same image under the quotient map from the square to the torus. So that's not the vertex labelling you want to use in order to compute $\partial U$.
Instead, just examine how the three edges of $U$ are oriented in relation to the three vertices of $U$:

Edge $a$ of $U$ is oriented from the the lower left vertex to the upper left;
Edge $b$ of $U$ is oriented fom the upper left to the upper right;
Edge $c$ of $U$ is oriented from the lower left to the upper right.

So $v_1$ must be the lower left of $U$, $v_2$ must be the upper left, and $v_3$ must be the upper right. With that you get
$$\partial U = a + b - c
$$
A similar consideration of triangle $L$ gives $v_1$ as the lower left vertex of $L$, $v_2$ as the lower right, and $v_3$ as the upper right, and so
$$\partial L = b + a - c
$$
